# Grails UrlMapping route to fixed controller and action

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I made the following rule in my UrlMapping file and now all my controllers are matching to the (`"/$username"`) mapping, not the first one (`"/$controller/$action?/$id?"`).

The idea here was to list all public items from an user using a short url. It works but it breaks all others controllers.

```
static mappings = {

    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/$username" {
        controller = 'user'
        action = 'publicItens'
    }

    "/"(controller:'usuario', action: 'index' )
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

How can I map it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved!

I just wrote some code in the UrlMappings to create rules automatically for each controller in the application. Using this approach when the user types /appname/controllerName then the rule created automatically is considered in place of the "$/username" rule.

The critical point is that the use of ApplicationHolder which is deprecated. That can fixed writing your own ApplicationHolder.

```
static mappings = {

    //creates one mapping rule for each controller in the application
    ApplicationHolder.application.controllerClasses*.logicalPropertyName.each { cName ->
        "/$cName" {
            controller = cName
        }
    }

    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
    }

    "/$username" {
        controller = 'usuario'
        action = 'itensPublicos'
    }

    "/"(controller:'usuario', action: 'index' )
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `/users/$username` to the URL mapping. This is the simplest way how to achieve your goals.

```
 "/users/$username" {
        controller = 'user'
        action = 'publicItens'
    }
```

Comment: Actually I would like to map it without the controller name.

Comment: @lfrodrigues so what do you want to happen when `$username` happens to be the same as one of the controller names? For instance, what if you have a controller named `search` but someone sets their user name to "search"? How would grails know which URL mapping to pick?

Comment: In that case grails would pick the controller. The controller that creates new users should be modified to avoid that an user with a controller name be registered.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably also exclude the user and usario controllers in the first url mapping constraints(notEqual)

http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/notEqual.html

Comment: I tested your approach but I had no success. It keeps using the "/$username" rule instead of the "/$controller/$action?/$id?". Ex: I have a controller named "top" and when I type localhost:8080/appname/top in the address bar the rule maps to the "user" controller instead the top controller.